# "Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime" Error When clicking submit button

Tags: asp.net, runtime-error, publish

Im trying to publish my ASP.NET website.
I have a Backend function, a WCF-service (i don't think this is the problem, because i can access it in debug and so on)

The problem is that I publish this website to a WebHotel, and that works like a charm.
After the publish i can browse to the startpage of the website. but when im clicking on a submitbutton(log in).
it throws Error (refer bottom of post).

The CustomError tag in webconfig i have changes multiple times to "Off", "On" and "RemoteOnly".
It doesn't show any specific error at all.

the same project have Worked before, but suddenly this appeared. its like a lotto.

I also catches any error in the application and WCF-Service and store it in a database, but nothing of these errors appears.

any ideas what this is?

Dont know if this matter but I have a other ASP.NET page on a subdomain of this domain.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Clarify your statement on "subdomain" in application terms. Is it a "sub-application" (child) and if so, is it marked as such? Your comment about not seeing any errors even if you change web.config _seems_ to indicate this (because the "parent" web config) is "inherited" by child app. But this is a guess and for anyone to give an useful input you need to provide more.

Comment: The Subdomain App is not connected to the main domain. But the two sites use the same DB and WCF-Service. 
Actually the two sites (Sub and Main) is two separated projects. and i have no control over the Main Project right now. (im working on SubDomain).

Comment: Still unclear - I'll assume you mean they are completely separate ASP.net applications. If so changing your web.config to show errors should give you detailed error info which this forum will need to even begin to help. Guessing is all that can be done without debug info.

Comment: I have The CustomError Tag set to "Off" == "All callers receive complete exception information." (MSDN)

I Called the other guy who is working on the main domain. And he said that he also had CustomErrors Set to "Off".

Now i have published a new WCF-Service with customerrors enabled also, but still i don't get any details of the fault. I wonder if it has anything to do with the Webhotel-host ?

Answer (score 0):

This Was solved with trial and error.
Something was wrong with the FTP server that i uploaded the project to.
I think by reseting the DNS and reactivate the domain in the webhotel fixed the issue together with a complete reset by the FTP.